# How can I get these two suburbs with SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I want to get a departure and destination suburb in my SQL.

```
SELECT jp.`id`,
     CONCAT(u.`first_name`, " ", u.`last_name`) AS `name`,
     jp.`departure_time`,
     jp.`destination_time`,
     s.`suburb` AS `departure_suburb`


FROM `journey_planning` AS `jp`
JOIN `users` AS `u` ON jp.`driver_id` = u.`id`
JOIN `suburbs` AS s ON jp.`departure_suburb_id` = s.`id`
  OR jp.`destination_suburb_id` = s.`id`
```

As you can see, there is a `departure_suburb_id` and `destination_suburb_id`. I need them to map to their relative value in the `suburbs` table.

At the moment, this is returning two rows, both with identical information except the different suburb name (however both as `departure_suburb`, obviously).

I'm no SQL expert, so I'm not sure what I should be doing. I thought about using subqueries, but I thought there was probably a way without them and avoiding two lookups.

How should I modify this query to return what it is now, though with `departure_suburb` and `destination_suburb` pointing to the right values in the `suburbs` table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to join to the suburbs table twice, once for departure, once for destination. Also it's a good habit to be in to type the type of join you're using, even though "INNER JOIN" is implied!

```
SELECT jp.`id`,
     CONCAT(u.`first_name`, " ", u.`last_name`) AS `name`,
     jp.`departure_time`,
     jp.`destination_time`,
     s.`suburb` AS `departure_suburb`
     s2.`suburb` AS `destination_suburb` 

FROM `journey_planning` AS `jp`
JOIN `users` AS `u` ON jp.`driver_id` = u.`id`
JOIN `suburbs` AS s ON jp.`departure_suburb_id` = s.`id`
JOIN `suburbs` AS s2 ON jp.`destination_suburb_id` = s2.`id`
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    jp.id
  , CONCAT(u.first_name, " ", u.last_name) AS name
  , jp.departure_time
  , jp.destination_time
  , dep.suburb AS departure_suburb
  , dest.suburb AS destination_suburb

FROM journey_planning AS jp
  JOIN users AS u 
    ON jp.driver_id = u.id
  JOIN suburbs AS dep 
    ON jp.departure_suburb_id = dep.id
  JOIN suburbs AS dest 
    OR jp.destination_suburb_id = dest.id
```

How can it be done otherwise? (I wouldn't recommend this for a query with simple JOINs like yours). Since all the relationships are 1-to-many with many on the `jp` table, it can be done like this:

```
SELECT
    jp.id
  , CONCAT( ( SELECT first_name
              FROM users
              WHERE jp.driver_id = users.id
            )
          , " "
          , ( SELECT last_name
              FROM users
              WHERE jp.driver_id = users.id
            )
          )
      AS name
  , jp.departure_time
  , jp.destination_time
  , ( SELECT suburb
      FROM suburbs
      WHERE jp.departure_suburb_id = suburbs.id
    ) 
      AS departure_suburb
  , ( SELECT suburb
      FROM suburbs
      WHERE jp.destination_suburb_id = suburbs.id
    ) 
      AS destination_suburb

FROM journey_planning AS jp
```

As you can see, it gets quite complicated, especially when you want to show more than one field from a table, like the first and last name from table users.

Comment: +1 thanks for answering. Is there any other way to go about this? Just interested :)

Comment: Yes, but when you can use JOINs to relate data from many tables, it's usually the best way. If there are indexes on the foreign keys (`driver_id`, `departure_suburb_id` and `destination_suburb_id`), the query will be pretty fast.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I considered that as the alternative, but you can see why I didn't want to do it :)

Answer (score 0):

Just JOIN suburbs again with a different table alias:

```
SELECT jp.`id`,
    CONCAT(u.`first_name`, " ", u.`last_name`) AS `name`,
    jp.`departure_time`,
    jp.`destination_time`,
    departure_suburb.`suburb` AS `departure_suburb`,
    destination_suburb.`suburb` AS `destination_suburb`
FROM `journey_planning` AS `jp`
    JOIN `users` AS `u` ON jp.`driver_id` = u.`id`
    JOIN `suburbs` AS depart_suburb ON jp.`departure_suburb_id` = s.`id`
    JOIN `suburbs` AS destination_suburb ON jp.`destination_suburb_id` = ss.`id`
```